# Prevent saving images from website (save whole page)

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to prevent users from saving images when they do a `save as`?

I have already disabled right click in the pages using javascript as well as adding the following header:

```
<meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no" />
```

But if I go for example in `OPERA` and do `page -> save as -> html file with images` all the images will get saved. IS there a way to counter this?!

Comment: seriously what is this, 1999?

Comment: Sean welcome  to the future (:

Comment: something should be done with SO reputation system . Seriously ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is not. If an HTTP client can download it, it can save it. It is a futile effort to try and counter this.

**Edit**: Also, I'd like to point out that most browsers allow the user to forcefully (re-)enable the right-click menu on evil websites who try and take that freedom away from them.

Answer (score 7):

They will always be saved. Your browser caches images locally anyway, so they'll always be downloaded to a users machine and if they wanted to take them, they would.

The only way to stop images from being saved is **don't put them on the internet.**

Answer (score 2):

No, there is always a way for users to get your images.  If you dont want your images reused consider watermarking them if this is appropriate or branding them with the company logo.

Disabling right click will just annoy the hell out of users who probably wouldnt steal your images anyway, and be a minor inconvenience to those who would.

No right click? Just screenshot the page, maybe view source and go directly to the image file, etc etc.

Just out of curiosity, why do you even want to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do what the author of [this page](http://www.romancortes.com/blog/homer-css/) did with a picture of Homer Simpson. Look ma, no `<img>`!